# How to create and attach a file to an email without saving the file?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-mail

I am trying to add a function to my website where a button will attach a PDF of the window to an email that the user enters. I am using Flask-Mail to send the email, and just printing the window to create the PDF. Right now, the email will send, and I am able to attach something. The problem is that I would like to create the PDF and attach it without the file saving to the user's device.

How should I go about this? My code is written in Python and JavaScript. I have seen other threads with c# code where you can use the memory stream to do something like attaching a file without saving it. Is there something similar that could be achieved with Python?

Comment: How do you generate your pdf ? With Python or javascript ?

Comment: I generate the pdf with javascript using the window.print() function.

Comment: Why is the file saved on the user's device? You are sending it to the server, right? Do you want to send it withtou saving it on _the server_?

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to working with websites. I hadn't thought of that. Could I create and save the PDF to the server without prompting the user? I would like for the PDF to be named the same thing each time and saved to an uploads folder on the server. Then I can just attach that to the email from the uploads folder. Thank you for your help thus far!